# I'm having an argument out of bounds exception

Tags: c#, arraylist

I am using an arraylist, and have this list[list.Count -1], and it gives me argument out of range exception, why is it? if the count of the list is the number of elements it contains, than list[list.count] shouldnt be out of range, this is how i'm adding items to the list:

```
string query = "SELECT Title, Type, Contents, Rank,Audio FROM dbo.Article,dbo.ArticleJournal WHERE dbo.Article.ArticleId = dbo.ArticleJournal.ArticleId AND dbo.ArticleJournal.JournalId LIKE @id ;";
List<Codes.ArticleJ> list = new List<Codes.ArticleJ>();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
         connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
        query, connection);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string Title = reader.GetString(0);
            string type = reader.GetString(1);
            String Contents = reader.GetString(2);
            int rnk = reader.GetInt32(3);
            String Audio = reader.GetString(4);

            Codes.ArticleJ article = new Codes.ArticleJ(Title, type,     Contents, rnk, Audio);
            list.Add(article);
        }
    }
    finally 
    { 
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Then i'm doing this:

```
if (list[list.Count -1].rank == list.Count)
```

Comment: What if it's empty?

Comment: Ok. Can we see how you add elements in the arrayList?

Comment: As an aside, why are you still using ArrayList at all, rather than a generic collection?

Comment: What is the value of `list.Count` at the time of the error?

Comment: Why do you have a try-finally block? Your using scope will close the connection

Answer (score 0):

Well, if list.count = 0 (i.e. an empty list) and you subtract 1 from it, it'll throw that exception.

Answer (score 0):

As Damon said earlier, if you have an arraylist that starts at 0 and you're subtracting 1 from 0, you are getting -1 which doesn't exist in terms of arrays/arraylists.

Think of it this way, the only way an array will be out of bounds is when your program is asking for a array key when it does not exist. Example:

```
//Say you had this array
int [] myArray = new int [5];

//Then you wanted to add a number to myArray[6]
myArray[6] = 15;

//You will get the exception because you did not define myArray to have 7 keys (0-6)

//This also goes for negative integers
myArray[-1] = 15; 

//You will also get the exception because 0 is the lowest key an array can go
//Negative numbers do not exist
```